# How can I get first first N decimal digits of a float represented as an int?

Tags: python, numba

For example, if I have:

```
12.43564
```

I'd like to be able to get `43564` as an `int`. Or, if the float has many decimal places, it would be OK to just get the first N decimals as integer. For example, if N is `3`, for `12.43564` I would then get `435`. Unfortunately, I cannot just convert the number to a string as I need to use this in a numba compiled function, where the conversion of a float to a string is not possible as per [this open issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4758).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can create a function outside of Your numba decorated function that will do the conversion, no?

Comment: No that's not possible because Numba-compiled code cannot call regular a regular python function. But the trick with `int((x - int(x)) * 10000)` worked very well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typecast it to a string, split on the period, get the N digits you want.

```
>>> x = 1.23456789
str(x)
>>> str(x)
'1.23456789'
>>> str(x).split('.')
['1', '23456789']
>>> str(x).split('.')[1][:4]
'2345'
```

Based on edit,

Substract the int part. Multiply by 10000 to get the first 4.

```
>>> (x - int(x)) * 10000
2345.678899999999
>>> int((x - int(x)) * 10000)
2345
```

Comment: Check out: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a string, split it at the decimal, and slice it:

```
x = 12.43564
print(str(x).split(".")[1][:3])
```

Note that slicing won't throw any errors if you try to get extra digits:

```
str(x).split(".")[1][:1000]
```

will just return `43564`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that works with negative numbers too

```
def digits(x,N):
    return int((abs(x) % 1) * 10**N)
    
print(digits(1.23456,2))
print(digits(-1.23456,3))
print(digits(1.23,5))
```

Gives:

```
23
234
23000
```

Answer (score 1):

Without converting to string, you can try `numpy.modf`:

```
> np.modf(d)
(0.43563999999999936, 12.0)

> int(np.modf(d)[0] * 1e3)
435
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and purely mathematical approach that doesn't require any ext lib:

```
n = 12.43564
result = n % int(n)
while not int(result) or int(result) % 10:
    result *= 10
result = int(result / 10)
```